# ARC static interface issue

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have the following in my property

```
@property (nonatomic,readonly) NSString itemName;
```

originally readonly == copy i'm trying to migrate to ARC so tried assign || strong but all failed

with build error:

> Interface type cannot be statically allocated

Can someone help me out here I dont understand this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this to:

```
@property (nonatomic,readonly) NSString* itemName;
```

You're missing out the asterisk which correctly turns this into an NSString reference.

Comment: do you have any  links explaining these properties key words from memory perspective?

Comment: Apart from the Objective-C 2.0 reference, no. But it's fairly obvious. You can't allocate a static Cocoa object as a property. Change the `readonly` to `strong` now and, with the proper `NSString*` type you'll be fine. You don't pass around Cocoa objects - you pass around pointers to Cocoa objects.